# How to output a file with the least words in linux

Tags: linux, bash

I want to write a script that takes one argument (the name of a directory) and that directory contains three .txt files with random words. The first file contains 1 word the second 6 words and the third one contains 3 words. I want to display the name and the amount of words in a file that has the least words.
My code so far:

```
#! /bin/bash
if [ $# -gt 0 ]
then
    cd $1
    number=0
    for i in *
    do  
        var=($(wc -w $i))
        if [ $var -gt $number ]
        then
          number=$var
        else
        wc -w $i    
        fi
    done
else
    echo "Please type the name of a directory"  
fi
```

Comment: What bit are you stuck on?

Comment: You have stored the word count for the largest number of words, also use a variable to keep track of the file in every iteration

Comment: the if statement. I want it to compare all files and wc -w the one with the least words

Comment: Also you need to have a `if [ -f "$i" ]` check inside the for-loop, as the `wc` may run on directories too if present, which you don't need.

Answer (score 1):

use `wc` to show count the words, numerically sort the list, and pick the first element.

```
#!/bin/sh
dir=$1
if [ -d "${dir}" ]; then
   wc -w ${dir}/* | sort -n | head -1
else
   echo "usage: $0 <directory>" 1>&2
   echo "     show file in directory with the fewest words" 1>&2
   exit 1
fi
```

as @Leon pointed out, the above will only work properly if `${dir}` contains *some* files (not an empty directory) and if it only contains *files* (no subdirectories).

A slightly more complicated solution is to use `find` to limit the examined paths to files. you can also use it to traverse into subdirectories:

```
find "${dir}" -type f -exec wc -w {} + | sort -n | head -1
```

Comment: Cool solution. If `${dir}` contains any sub directories with no files then it will output that as having word count 0. It also returns 0 if `${dir}` is `.` A work around seems to be using `find` - `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec wc -w {} +| sort -n | head -1`